# calling out children in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a JS function which resizes images under the `.resizer`in my HTML in have nested the image tag the following way.

```
<section id="homeSlide" class="shadow">
    <div class="contentHolder">
        <img class='opaque resize' src="http://www.colette.fr/media/push/swa_mmm_001255.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="contentHolder">
        <img class="resize" src="http://www.colette.fr/media/push/EGIFT_01234.jpg" />
    </div>
</section>
```

In my JS i have the following structure..

```
function ebi() {
var homeSlide = document.getElementById('homeSlide');
var myImgNodes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < homeSlide.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var childNode = homeSlide.childNodes[i];
    if (childNode.nodeType == 1 && childNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
        myImgNodes.push(childNode);
    }
}
```

However this function doesn't seem to be resizing?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/RreUL/)

Comment: why not `$('#homeSlide img').each(...)` since you've tagged this with jquery?

Comment: Where is the element with id `slideContent` ?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `childNodes` of 'slideContent' (or 'homeSlide,' you mix your id's there) are the `div`s, not the img. You need to get the children of those children.

Comment: Any reason for the jQuery tag?

Comment: @A.Wolff Not to get more attention, obviously. This question is packed full of jQuery!

Comment: Please post all your code in stack. So far you are only showing 1 function while your example shows alot more. If for some reason your jsfiddle item would disapear, this question would be totally useless for stack.

Comment: @DamienOvereem you've misunderstood the question completely. If you look at the HTML i have #homeSlider > div > img. In my JS i am calling the childern of homeSlide.. var homeSlide = document.getElementById('homeSlide'); If you take a look at the answers below you'll notice it should be #homeSlide img!

Comment: Almost yes. You were iterating through the divs instead of the images. Might aswell go `$('#homeSlide img.resize').each( function(key,element) { element.resize(.....)  });` though :) Since you are using jquery, your code can be much shorter. Unless the Jquery tag on this question is invalid, in that case please remove the tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I'd do implement `ebi` (no jQuery needed, assuming IE8+)

```
function ebi() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('#homeSlide img.resize');
}
```

( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SByu/) )

Comment: I'll gladly add a solution for really old IE if you want, it's not complicated - just uncommon given the market share.

Answer (score 1):

your img nodes are not in the first level you can easily try jQuery:

```
$('#homeSlide img').each(function(){
//do your task
})
```

or without `jQuery` try this:

```
function ebi() {
    var slideContent = document.getElementById('slideContent');
    var myImgNodes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < slideContent.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var divNode = slideContent.childNodes[i];
        if (divNode.nodeType == 1 && divNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div"){
            for (var j = 0; j < divNode.childNodes.length; j++) {
                var childNode = divNode.childNodes[j];
                if (childNode.nodeType == 1 && childNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
                    myImgNodes.push(childNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is your [jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mehranhatami/QFK6Y/2/) check this out.

Comment: I don't see any advantage of this jQuery solution over the native one in my answer. Moreover, the native solution you provided is very convoluted and can be done in a much simpler way even without QSA.

Comment: On a cheerier note - you don't need to do `toLowerCase` on tag names, they're _always_ uppercase,m you can just check against `"DIV"` and `"IMG"`.

Comment: your right, as I've gone through this trouble before (difference between tagnames like `div` and `DIV`) i have become obsessed with it. and I really don't like getting convoluted. I just voted up your answer.